# Android SearchView that looks like the material design

Tags: android, searchview

I was looking to implement an in app search screen and by searching a bit I found [this google material design link](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/search.html) with a sexy search box

[image]

The app AirBnb has a very similar style (if not the same)

[image]

But I cannot figure out how they manage to style that searchView like this.. (especially aibnb with that padding around the search view)

Mine looks like this..
[image]

Could someone point to some material to arrive such a design?